# CloneButton on DataGrid goes to edit page

Tags: reactjs, clone, react-admin

I have following code:

```
<Datagrid rowClick="edit">
  <TextField source="id" label="Id" />
  <TextField source="token" label="Token" />
  <LinkResourceField
    label="Company"
    source="company.id"
    reference={record =>
      `${Pluralize.plural(get(record, 'company.category', 'company'))}`
    }
    display="company.name"
    sortable={false}
  />
  <TextField source="status" label="Status" />
  <CloneButton />
</Datagrid>
```

CloneButton does show up but when I click it, it first goes to create page but then it ends up going to edit page for the record I clicked on.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  Anyway to setup CloneButton so that it stops it from triggering rowClick?

Thanks for reading and your help.

Comment: That's a react-admin bug ; the CloneButton should stop the click event propagation so that the datagrid row never receives the rowClick event. I advise you to open an issue in the react-admin tracker.

Comment: Thanks! I will submit a bug.

Comment: For anyone else coming to this question, this is what was submitted to github issue: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3005

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto Please check the other answer below. Could react-admin support this also as an option? Have our own onClick to do something and then run the internal onClick handler too? Optionally (through a different prop maybe)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone for helping.

I was able to put up a bug & a PR to resolve this issue on react-admin.
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/3006

This is now fixed with react-admin version 2.8.2.

Everyone's comments were super helpful and I wouldn't have been able to get here without it.

Also a big thank you to react-admin team for quickly approving and releasing a new version.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do this:

```
<CloneButton onClick={event => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()
  // do something here
} />
```

Comment: Not quite since I am using react-admin's component for this.  I don't have a way to ``//do something here`` since that is controlled by react-admin.

Comment: Could react-admin support this also as an option? Have our own `onClick` to do something and then run the internal `onClick` handler too?